# How can I use the Neptune editor?

Tags: editors

Neptune is a web-based proofing framework for LATEX authors. It is part of TEXFolio, the complete journal production system on the cloud.
But the question where is the link to start editing?

Neptune website: https://neptune.texfolio.org/main.html

Comment: Isn't it part of a commercial article editing system?

Comment: Well on texfolio.org it says that this is "Free/Open source". So, maybe you should just ask them directly.

Comment: Is there a documentation available for nepture or texfolio? I couldn't find either.

Comment: I think it rather says that it is "based on free software", not that it is free software itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can request free access to it if you are a scholar.
https://stmdocs.com/gray-flyer.pdf

Otherwise, I guess you will need to pay to get it as "software as a service" (SaaS).